# Building Whitelabel Rocket Chat app results in build Failure

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradlew, rocket.chat

I am white labeling the Rocket Chat app for my server. I have everything working in the test environment. [e.g. yarn android] I am now ready to build an apk to push out to my server members. The issue I'm having is that running `gradlew bundleRelease` in the "/android" folder always results in an error saying,

> Task :app:processBugsnagE2eFossReleaseManifest FAILED                                                                                                                                                                                         FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                                                                                                                                                        * What went wrong:                                                                                                      Execution failed for task ':app:processBugsnagE2eFossReleaseManifest'.                                                  > Bugsnag: Your AndroidManifest.xml is missing one or more of                                                             apiKey/versionCode/buildUuid/versionName/package, which are required to upload to bugsnag.                              apiKey=null

I'm really not sure what could be causing the problem as I have a bugsnag apikey declared in "gradle.properties". Any help would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE:** It turns out that I was using the wrong build command. Instead of using `gradlew bundleRelease`, I needed to using the command `gradlew bundleExperimentalPlayRelease`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: It turns out that I was using the wrong build command. Instead of using gradlew bundleRelease, I needed to using the command gradlew bundleExperimentalPlayRelease.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. You have to use real bugsnag api key. If you don't have one then it is [suggested](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative/issues/4008#issuecomment-1145921730) to remove bugsnag.
2. Try adding api key to your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` as mentioned in bugsnag [docs](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/react-native/manual-setup/#android) and this [issue](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.ReactNative/issues/3422#issuecomment-957513622).

```
<application ...>
  <meta-data android:name="com.bugsnag.android.API_KEY"
             android:value="your-api-key-here"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Okay, I gave that a try. First I tried a new Bugsnag API Key and that didn't work. Then I added the key manually to the AndroidManifest.xml and that also didn't work. However, the second option resulted in a new error. Am I even running the right build command? Thanks for you help btw.

Comment: Try doing `gradlew clean` before `gradlew bundleRelease`

Comment: Okay. I ran `gradlew clean` then `gradlew bundleRelease` and it failed at the same task but this time with the error, `AAPT: error: resource color/primary_dark (aka project_name:color/primary_dark) not found.` If I remove that line in the AndroidManifest.xml file it just moves to another line and says that it's not found. Is there a way to remove the bundleE2eFossRelease from being bundled?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Turns our that there was another build command I was supposed to use. After using `gradlew bundleExperimentalPlayRelease` and making sure the keystore file was configured properly, the build was successful. Thank you for your help!